# Button Created Programmatically Requires to be Clicked Twice

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have this strange behaviour with my ASP.NET Web Form app.

In my Login page, if there are existing sessions, it creates a table that shows all the existing sessions with a row with two buttons to 1) go to that particular session or 2) terminate the session.

If there are 2 sessions, and you terminate one of them, the session selected to be terminated will terminate with one session remaining in the table.

But with the remaining session, it requires two clicks for either of the buttons to respond. After the first click, the page flashes, so I assume a postback was triggered so the page would've been initialized.

Comment: Shall we guess?  (Seriously, we need to see the relevant code segment.  Better yet, a fiddle that demonstrates the problem).

Comment: No one is going to take your question seriously without a minimal example with some code.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a little troubleshooting to see which of these is a problem:

1. The session is terminated on the first click, but the display isn't properly updated till the second click
2. The session is not terminated until the second click

If it's the former, the likely problem is that the table is updated in Form_Load, but the click event handler doesn't execute until after Form_Load has finished.  To fix this, render the table in Form_PreRender instead-- this event fires after the click handler.